# sum two numbers in \ifnum

Tags: conditionals, calculations

I would like to implement a command in LaTeX which would sum two numbers before comparing them to a third number as follows:

```
\ifnum #1+45>0
    above
\else 
    left
\fi
```

where `#1` is an angle in degrees.

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Please, could you help me how to fix that?

Many thanks.

The whole code after advice from Werner:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compare}[1]{%
  \ifdim\dimexpr#1pt+45pt\relax>\z@\relax
    above%
  \else 
    left%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% define arrows
% general right to left double harpoon
% define four connection position #5 and connect the arrows in +-5degrees
% first parameter define origin node 
% second parameter define destination node,
% third parameter label of top arrow
% fourth parameter label of bottom arrow
% fifth parameter define connection point - angle in degrees on the origin node
\newcommand{\grldh}[5]{
    \draw[-left to,thick] ({#1}.{#5+5}) -- node[\compare{#5}] {\scriptsize #3} ({#2}.{#5+175});
    \draw[left to-,thick] ({#1}.{#5+355}) -- node[below] {\scriptsize #4} ({#2}.{#5+185}); 
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    state/.style={
    % The shape:
    circle,minimum size=3mm,rounded corners=3mm,
    },
     scale=1.5]
    % draw nodes
    \path
          (0,5)  node (N05) [state] {$C$}
          (1,5)  node (N15) [state] {$O$}
          (1,4)  node (N14) [state] {$I$};
    % draw paths
    \grldh{N05}{N15}{$\alpha$}{$\beta$}{0};
    \grldh{N05}{N14}{$\gamma$}{$\delta$}{-45};
    \grldh{N15}{N14}{$\gamma$}{$\delta$}{-90};

    \end{tikzpicture}    
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Also have you seen the `tikz-cd` package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One would assume that you're dealing with real numbers that you want to compare. In that sense, a comparison of numbers is not appropriate, since they do not work with fractional components. Dimensions (or lengths) on the other hand do. You can trick a function to work with lengths rather than numbers in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compare}[1]{%
  \ifdim\dimexpr#1pt+45pt>\z@
    above%
  \else 
    left%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$1$ is \compare{1}, % 1 + 45 = 46 > 0 -> above
while $-90$ is \compare{-90} % -90 + 45 = -45 < 0 -> left
and $-45$ is \compare{-45}. % -45 + 45 = 0 ... -> left
\end{document}
```

The function `\compare{<num>}` uses `<num>` in a "dimension" form as `<num>pt`, adds `45pt` to that, checks if this is greater than `\z@` (or `0pt`) and conditions accordingly.

Note the use of `%` to avoid spurious spaces. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your example works perfectly.

In my case, I intend to include the \compare command in definition of other command (please see the updated code attached), which does not work.

Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @Tomas: Remove both `\relax` commands within `\compare`. Give some feedback once you've tested.